# Normal for 17 instances of Node.js JavaScript Runtime to be loaded into memory when the only open application windows are Windows Update and taskmgr?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, node.js

Is it normal for 17 instances of Node.js JavaScript Runtime to be loaded into memory when the only open application windows are Windows Update and Task Manager? They average about 3MB RAM consumption each, but they're not consuming any CPU or Disk I/O, Network resources or GPU.

EDIT: I see they're all associated with Visual Studio 2022. But VS isn't open.

Comment: Like the name suggests, it's just a runtime. The command line tells you what it's running. // Windows does not ship with Node.js.

Comment: To add to what @DanielB is saying .. although Visual Studio has support for NodeJS, it has ZERO to do with Microsoft other than the fact that the IDE will allow you to author and debug it.

Comment: That’s not entirely true, @SeñorCMasMas. Visual Studio launches a gazillion sub-processes nowadays, some of which are Node.js. Example use cases are TypeScript and ESLint.

Comment: True that @DanielB  .. I wasn't thinking about those.  Even then.. the way NodeJS uses multiple processes to achieve async behavior is not Microsoft's design.  I have three seperate instances of VS open right now and not a single instance of NodeJS.  I do however have a whole BUNCH of other sub-processes. :P

Comment: They might be [Worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). How many cores do you see in *Task Manager >Performance > CPU* ?

Comment: No matter what.. if he isn't actually RUNNING VS.. what the heck are those processes running for?

Comment: @harrymc  It was Windows Update time, and I installed the update before I saw your question about Performance.  They're gone now.  But I'd really like to know why so many instances of the Node.js runtime were spawned. Isn't it supposed to be able to handle multiple requests?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a multi-threaded environment, which is rather false.

The classical notion of Threads has them all running in the context
of one process and sharing the entire memory of the process.

However, threads in Node.js run each in its own separate process and they
communicate by mechanisms such as semaphores and shared memory segments.

You apparently ran under Node.js a task that was multi-threaded,
which caused Node.js to spawn enough child processes to handle
all the threads.

From your account, it seems that Node.js will reduce the number of these
processes sometime after their thread terminates.

You will find more information in the article
[Node.js v20.0.0 documentation - Worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  "sometime after their thread terminates":  If the threads where created the last time I had VS2022 open, that was two days previous to my discovering them.

Comment: I can't be sure that the cause was VS2022. I also haven't found any information about when and how it decides to release the threads, which is why I used the vague "sometime".